# Where to fetch data for permissions in Clean Architecture?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, clean-architecture

Using Clean Architecture I need to implement permissions.

I decided to implement additional permissions layer PermissionsChecker.
My permissions depend on database state. I have assigned permissions to the user in database as well as it depends on the state of the domain object.
I have adapter for my database. Now where should I fetch data using that adapter?

1. Should I fetch data on the use case level and pass it down to the PermissionChecker?
2. Or Should I fetch data on the permission layer? But then PermissionChecker would have dependency to database port.
3. Or other solution that I didn't think of?

Comment: without knowing more about your design it is quite difficult to give a recommendation. maybe you could add some code snippets or diagrams to your question?

Comment: Is it more complex than role management? I didn't get how you authorize actions. With a role management system, it's better to authorize your APIs than leak the authorization to other layers. If you have any complex rules that you need to fetch an aggregate/entity (not the user aggregate/entity, I mean sth like Product aggregate/entity) you should do it in your domain model.

Answer (score 0):

The right answer depends on your actual need.
It depends on whether the permission issue you are facing is simply a data access issue or a feature access issue.

While I assume this is a feature access issue, I think as mentioned in the comment it's not a good idea to mix permission management with database.
The database is just a storage tool, keep its role as simple as possible.
Doing this in the database or data access layer will make your design a nightmare.
In this case you will find yourself passing in the user identity and going through all the layers until you find the database.

If your project is divided into 3 layers: Application layer (endpoints like web API, soap...), Domain layer (business layer), Infrastructure layer.
Personally, I consider permission management to be part of the Application layer.
Or it could be another layer: the authorization layer between the application layer and the domain layer.

This allows you to keep the domain layer untouchable when the permission constraint changes.
One of the goals of good design is to reduce the impact of dependencies on the domain layer and permission management is a kind of dependency.

This is also allows you to test/validate domain layer regardless the user permission issue.

A feature-oriented design may be useful for your case.

If the problem is about data access issue, it means all features are allowed but data perimeter are different from one user to another, in this case it will be more complicated to implement I think.